# Why does bool(xml.etree.ElementTree.Element) evaluate to False?

Tags: python, boolean

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
e = ET.Element('Brock',Role="Bodyguard")
print bool(e)
```

Why is an `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element` considered `False`?

I know that I can do `if e is not None` to check for existence. But I would **strongly** expect `bool(e)` to return `True`.

Comment: I would too. Was really surprised when I discovered the same behavior this morning and was happy to find this thread.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

As it turns out, `Element` objects are considered a `False` value if they have no children.

I found this in the source:

```
def __nonzero__(self):
    warnings.warn(
        "The behavior of this method will change in future versions.  "
        "Use specific 'len(elem)' or 'elem is not None' test instead.",
        FutureWarning, stacklevel=2
        )
    return len(self._children) != 0 # emulate old behaviour, for now
```

Even the inline comment agrees with you -- this behavior is iffy ;)

Comment: Perhaps that's supposed to be analogous to the fact that an empty list is an object, but contains nothing. I don't like that though, because then an element with a name and even an attribute (and even text inside!) is considered "empty".

Comment: That's exactly right. A `list` is a mere container, i.e. defined by its elements. That isn't the case with an `Element`, exactly for the reasons you mentioned.

Comment: This iffy behavior cost me half a day of debugging even though I've been already bitten once by the same issue (but two months ago, managed to forgot it)

Comment: Oh, man, it's worse than you think. At least in the latest version of the source, the Element class that contains this definition [gets overridden](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.4/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L1654-L1660) by an alternate version defined with the C API, which does *not* emit the warning. (I discovered this because I was going to comment about how you should enable a logger and use `logging.captureWarnings(True)` to see warnings like these, but in testing realised that I, uh, couldn't see this warning when I do that.) What a goddamned mess the whole thing is.

Answer (score 21):

From the docs:

http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects

> Caution: Elements with no subelements will test as False. This behavior will change in future versions. Use specific len(elem) or elem is None test instead.

Comment: This API wart including some explanations of how it came to be is tracked in https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/83122