# Python XML element found but evaluates to False - how to check existence pythonically?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I am using `xml.etree` in Python to parse a SOAP response (don't ask...). The response contains a `<Success />` element.

I go and search it, find it and get an `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element` instance, let's call it `my_element`.

Yet said instance evaluates to `False`

- `bool(my_element)` is False
- `my_element.__nonzero__()` is `False` (using Python 2.7, otherwise I'd check `__bool__()` of course).

I assume that is because `my_element.text` is empty, as `<Success />` is an empty xml element.

I also assume this is a pythonic thing to do, as empty lists and dicts behave similarly - even though I think the meaning of an empty but existing XML element is different: What is the most pythonic way to check whether it is there?

Is it really the following?

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element
...
if isinstance(my_element, Element):
```

Comment: You didn't list the method you're using to find it.  But it probably returns None if it doesn't find one.  So... if my_element is not None

Comment: Perhaps `succeeded = myTree.find('Success') is not None`.  Ideally, the response should have been designed to have the Success element to always be present and set to True or False.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does bool(xml.etree.ElementTree.Element) evaluate to False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129996/why-does-boolxml-etree-elementtree-element-evaluate-to-false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `isinstance` is not the recommend way to check for non-existence of an `Element`.

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects):

> Caution: Elements with no subelements will test as False. This behavior will change in future versions. Use specific `len(elem)` or `elem is None` test instead.

From [the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#l250):

> ```
>    warnings.warn(
>         "The behavior of this method will change in future versions.  "
>         "Use specific 'len(elem)' or 'elem is not None' test instead.",
>         FutureWarning, stacklevel=2
>         )
> ```

To test for the non-existence of an element, do something like this:

```
my_element = tree.find('.//Success')
if my_element is not None:
    do_something(my_element)
```

Comment: didn't see the warning. Why would an element return false if it has no children? Can't understand that decision.

Comment: This defies all logical standards. Its testing for the existence of children attached to the element instead of the element it just returned. It should have implemented a test for children separately as that is a different context to the currently found element. Not a fan.

Comment: Yes, it is illogical. And that, I presume is why "this behavior will change in future versions."