# Find nodes defined in corrupted namespace

Tags: python, xml, xml-namespaces, elementtree

I've downloaded [this](http://udcdata.info/udcsummary-skos.zip) XML file.

I'm trying to get `includingNote` as follows:

```
...
namespaces = { "skos" : "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#", "xml" : "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace", 
                 "udc" : "http://udcdata.info/udc-schema#" }
...


includingNote = child.find("udc:includingNote[@xml:lang='en']", namespaces)
if includingNote:
  print includingNote.text.encode("utf8")
```

The scheme is located [here](http://udcdata.info/udc-scheme) and seems to be corrupted.

Is there a way I can print `includingNote` for each child node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that the `skos` prefix is not declared in udc-scheme, but searching the XML document is not a problem.

The following program extracts 639 `includingNote` elements:

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET

namespaces = {"udc" : "http://udcdata.info/udc-schema#",
              "xml" : "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"}

doc = ET.parse("udcsummary-skos.rdf")
includingNotes = doc.findall(".//udc:includingNote[@xml:lang='en']", namespaces)

print len(includingNotes)   # 639

for i in includingNotes:
    print i.text
```

Note the use of `findall()` and `.//` in front of the element name in order to search the whole document.

---

Here is a variant that returns the same information by first finding all `Concept` elements:

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET

namespaces = {"udc" : "http://udcdata.info/udc-schema#",
              "skos" : "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#",
              "xml" : "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"}

doc = ET.parse("udcsummary-skos.rdf")
concepts = doc.findall(".//skos:Concept", namespaces)

for c in concepts:
    includingNote = c.find("udc:includingNote[@xml:lang='en']", namespaces)
    if includingNote is not None:
        print includingNote.text
```

Note the use of `is not None`. Without that, it does not work. This seems to be a peculiarity of ElementTree. See [Why does bool(xml.etree.ElementTree.Element) evaluate to False?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20129996/407651).

Comment: len(includingNotes) prints 0

Comment: Well, it works for me. Please provide more details. What version of Python do you use? I use 2.7.12.