# Python ElementTree - Cannot find Element with attribute xml:lang

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Using ElementTree Python library, I need to find the element **display-name** and **parent**:

This is the Python code that is including also the sample XML:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ns = {'d': 'http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/catalog/2006-10-31'}

root = ET.fromstring("""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog xmlns="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/catalog/2006-10-31" catalog-id="my-catalog-id">
    <category category-id="my_id1">
        <display-name xml:lang="cs-CZ">Bla bla 1</display-name>
        <online-flag>false</online-flag>
    </category>
    <category category-id="my_id2">
        <display-name xml:lang="cs-CZ">Bla bla 2</display-name>
        <online-flag>false</online-flag>
        <parent>my_id1</parent>
    </category>
</catalog>
""")

def parse_category(category_node):
    category_id = category_node.attrib['category-id']
    is_online = category_node.find('d:online-flag', ns).text == "true"
    display_name_node = category_node.find('d:display-name', ns) # FIXME
    display_name = display_name_node.text if display_name_node else ''
    parent_node = category_node.find('d:parent', ns)
    parent_id = parent_node.text if parent_node else ''

    print("{} | {} | {} | {}".format(category_id, display_name, is_online, parent_id))

for child in root:
    print(child)
    if child.tag == "{{{0}}}category".format(ns['d']):
        parse_category(child)
```

Altough the **display_name_node** and **parent_node** variable are available for the node with id "my_id2", the text is not extracted in **display_name** and **parent_id** variables

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  What you've posted doesn't demonstrate the problem -- `parse_category()` isn't even called.

Comment: I think it's the problem discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20129996/407651

Comment: It has nothing to do with `xml:lang`.

Comment: @mzjn: Looks right.  Please add as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that changin from:

```
display_name = display_name_node.text if display_name_node else ''
parent_id = parent_node.text if parent_node else ''
```

to

```
display_name = display_name_node.text if display_name_node is not None else ''
parent_id = parent_node.text if parent_node is not None else ''
```

solves the problem, but I'm not quite sure why.